# MySQL MissingResourceException when running .jar from memory HikariCP

Tags: java, mysql, classloader, hikaricp

I've created an client program which uses Netty in order to download a .jar through a TCP socket and creates a new instance of JarInputStream

When I'm initializing the program everything loads up find untill connecting the database when it throws an MissingResourceException.

The original jar (The one that gets send trough netty) runs fine when normally ran via terminal / commandprompt. I don't think it is an issue in my code atleast.

I'm using HikariCP for database pooling and when connecting to the database it throws me this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.<clinit>(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:117)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolUtilities.initializeDataSource(PoolUtilities.java:110)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:157)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underlying exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale nl_NL
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:54)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale nl_NL
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:721)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:52)
    ... 38 more
```

I'm using:

mysql-connector-java : 5.1.37
HikariCP-java6       : 2.3.12

I can confirm that the LocalizedErrorMessages.properties file is indeed in com/mysql/jdbc.

Classloader I'm using: `http://pastebin.com/9VsV32Yg`

The original jar runs fine when executed from terminal / commandprompt.
The entrypoint in the original jar gets correctly executed in my TCP application as I can see startup output from it appearing in the console.

Hope someone knows whats causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement *public URL getResource(String name)* and various other resource API.  A ClassLoader does more than just load classes, it also provides access to other resources contained within the JAR.

Comment: Its not declared as abstract in java.lang.ClassLoader which I extend.

What is the correct URL.protocol for a resource inside a jar?

Comment: Why don't you override the method, set a breakpoint, and find out?  If I recall it starts with jar:// or something.